# Add Include to existing object in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've created an object in entity framework and want to include some related classes after the fact.  How can I do this or what keywords should I be searching for?

```
Order myOrder = 

context.Orders
        .Include("Category")
        .Include("Customer");

// Some logic here


myOrder = myOrder.Include("Supplier");
```

Comment: "*Explicit Loading*" is the keyword you can search for. If you tell us the EF version you are using and if you use `ObjectContext` or `DbContext` someone might answer with an example.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Will have to do some research on ObjectContext vs. DbContext as I'm working inside of someone else's system, but I do know I'm using POCO objects.

Comment: If you use POCOs with `ObjectContext` then it might be a problem. As far as I know in that constellation explicit loading is not supported. We have to look for another solution then (like simply querying the child entity/collection and assign it to the navigation property in `myOrder`, or something...).

Comment: Explicit loading works with ObjectContext as well but you must turn lazy loading off. Btw. why are you not using lazy loading?

Comment: Well I finally got it out of who set this up originally that the late loading or w/e it's called has been turned off.  The idea being not wanting to carry the database connection around everywhere?  Seemed to me like it would make things way more useful.

Comment: I guess @Ladislav meant something like this when using explicit loading with POCOs and `ObjectContext`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398445/using-createsourcequery-in-ctp4-code-first So, my second comment above is not quite correct.