# Cant add Includes (eager-loading) to correct place

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4, eager-loading

I'm trying to speed up some of my db tier functions by adding the proper Include statements to force eager loading and reduce the number of queries I make to the database.

However in 90% of the cases I run into the problem that I'm not at the correct "starting location" to enter the includes I want.

The simplest example I could come up with:

I have **Department**, **Course** and **Student** entities with many-to-many relationships between them (some courses below to multiple departments).

Now I have a function

`GetMasterCourses(Department dep)`  which does something like

`return dep.Courses.Where(c => c.level == "Master")`

The question is: how do I tell EF to load all students associated with each queried course?

The only solutions I have found are things like:

```
courseIDs = dep.Courses
  .Where(c => c.level == "Master").Select(c => c.courseID)
dbcontext.Courses
  .Include("Students")
  .Where(c => courseIDs.Contains(c.courseID) and c.level == Master)
```

This seems rather silly to have to do such a workaround just to be able to specify the correct Include. I have looked at many examples of Include and searched many questions on stackoverflow but can't really find anyone with this problem, eventhough it seems a quite common problem.

Comment: So your input is a `Department` that is (I assume) not part of a context.  What is your expected return type?

Comment: Are you eager-loading the `Courses` and `Students` when you load the `Department`?

Comment: The department is an argument of a function and is retrieved for example by `dbcontext.Departments.First()`.
The courses and students are indeed not eager loaded during this.
The expected return type would be IQueryable<Course>, so a set of courses which have their associated student collection eager loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you are selecting IDs.  It looks like you could just:

```
var courses = dep.Courses
  .Include(i => i.Students)
  .Where(c => c.level == "Master")
  .ToList() // or whatever
```

Comment: `dep.Courses.Include(i => i.Students)` is exactly what I WANT to do, but EF wont allow this. It seems I an only do includes on ObjectQuery objects (namely context.Courses). I can't use the include function on IQueryable  like association sets (dep.Courses).

I am using EF 4 not 5, but I havent seen a single example on the internet which is able to use include like that. If it is possible, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `DbContext` (EF >= 4.1):

```
dbContext.Departments.Attach(dep);
dep.Courses = dbContext.Entry(dep).Collection(d => d.Courses).Query()
    .Include(c => c.Students)
    .Where(c => c.level == "Master")
    .ToList();
```

If you are using `ObjectContext` with `EntityObject` derived entities (not POCOs):

```
objectContext.Departments.Attach(dep);
dep.Courses.Attach(dep.Courses.CreateSourceQuery()
    .Include("Students")
    .Where(c => c.level == "Master")
    .ToList());
```

If you are using `ObjectContext` with POCOs [it's possible but a bit hairy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3454159/270591).

All queries above are actually not the same like yours because maybe your `dep.Courses` collection does not contain all the courses that are related to the department `dep` in the database. (Who knows if you didn't remove a course from the `dep.Courses` collection after loading it?) In this case I'm afraid your query is the only way to go.

Because you were talking about performance and database request optimization: If you want to avoid the overhead to load the courses again (which you already have in memory) you could also try:

```
courseIDs = dep.Courses
    .Where(c => c.level == "Master").Select(c => c.courseID);
var studentDict = dbcontext.Courses
    .Where(c => courseIDs.Contains(c.courseID))
    .Select(c => new
    {
        courseID = c.courseID,
        Students = c.Students
    })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.courseID, x => x.Students);
foreach (var course in dep.Courses)
    course.Students = studentDict[course.courseID];
```

It loads less data but is not necessarily more performant because `Contains` has significant costs of translation into SQL for large `courseIDs` collections.