# Entity Framework Query: What's Happening Under the Covers Here?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have the following code.

```
var category = Office.Categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Description == name);
```

`Office` is a Framework Entity object that was read earlier.

Even though my database uses case-insensitive string comparisons, and one of the items matches exactly except for the case, this code is returning `null`.

My understanding of what is happening here is that `Office.Categories` is returning all related rows, and then those rows are being searched by regular LINQ, which is case-sensitive.

If so, that is horribly inefficient as I only want to return the row that matches my condition.

Can anyone confirm my understanding of this? And is it possible to force the filtering to take place in SQL so that I don't need to return the rows I'm not interested in? (And the text comparison will be case-insensitive?)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's not possible for us to know just from the code you've posted whether that's being evaluated in SQL or in memory.

Comment: Well, I believe I've established that it is not being evaluated in SQL. I can provide additional information if there are questions. But I'm really trying to find out the rules here that determine if it is evaluated in SQL, and if there's a way to override that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the `Office` object loaded (also depends on lazy loading, but assuming you're outside the context) then you're basically doing a linq-to-object query which is case sensitive. If you want to do linq-to-sql then you should do it differently, something like:

```
context.Offices.FirstOrDefault(o=>o.OfficeId == someId)
                  .Categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Description == name);
```

or

```
context.Categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.OfficeId == Office.OfficeId 
                                    && c.Description == name);
```

Comment: I have to run out but will experiment with these suggestions later.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, so you can't:

- Call the Categories property getter if using lazy loading because this causes EF to retrieve the full list of categories from the database
- Use eager loading, because this also causes the full list of categories to be loaded from the database

To avoid this, you can use the following code (from this answer here: [Using CreateSourceQuery in CTP4 Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398445/using-createsourcequery-in-ctp4-code-first))

```
    public ObjectQuery<T> CreateNavigationSourceQuery<T>(object entity, string navigationProperty)
    {
        var ose = this.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entity);
        var rm = this.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetRelationshipManager(entity);

        var entityType = (EntityType)ose.EntitySet.ElementType;
        var navigation = entityType.NavigationProperties[navigationProperty];

        var relatedEnd = rm.GetRelatedEnd(navigation.RelationshipType.FullName, navigation.ToEndMember.Name);

        return ((dynamic)relatedEnd).CreateSourceQuery();
    }
```

Add it to your context and call it to create an ObjectQuery.. you can call FirstOrDefault on this and it won't retrieve all entities from the database:

```
var category = context.CreateNavigationSourceQuery<Category>(Office, "Categories").FirstOrDefault(c => c.Description == name);
```

Comment: I'm having a little trouble reading this. Are there some typos? Did you mean I *can* do either of the following?